# How to use std::max with a custom comparator in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a vector of Hill structs and want to find the one with the heighest height. Here's my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <assert.h>
struct Hill {
    int height;
    int changed;
};
int main() {
    std::vector<Hill> hills(100);
    hills[0].height = 100;
    hills[1].height = 150;
    auto byHeight = [&](const Hill& a, const Hill& b) {
        return a.height < b.height;
    };
    Hill hill = std::max(hills.begin(), hills.end(), byHeight);
    assert(hill.height == 150);
}
```

But it fails to compile:

```
mcve.cpp:15:10: error: no viable conversion from 'const
      std::__1::__wrap_iter<Hill *>' to 'Hill'
    Hill hill = std::max(hills.begin(), hills.end(), byHeight);
         ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mcve.cpp:4:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not
      viable: no known conversion from 'const std::__1::__wrap_iter<Hill *>' to
      'const Hill &' for 1st argument
struct Hill {
       ^
mcve.cpp:4:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not
      viable: no known conversion from 'const std::__1::__wrap_iter<Hill *>' to
      'Hill &&' for 1st argument
struct Hill {
       ^
In file included from mcve.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:270:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__bit_reference:15:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:2627:12: error: 
      no matching function for call to object of type '(lambda at
      mcve.cpp:12:21)'
    return __comp(__a, __b) ? __b : __a;
           ^~~~~~
mcve.cpp:15:22: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::max<std::__1::__wrap_iter<Hill *>, (lambda at mcve.cpp:12:21)>'
      requested here
    Hill hill = std::max(hills.begin(), hills.end(), byHeight);
                     ^
mcve.cpp:12:21: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from
      'const std::__1::__wrap_iter<Hill *>' to 'const Hill' for 1st argument
    auto byHeight = [&](const Hill& a, const Hill& b) {
                    ^
2 errors generated.
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  You need `std::max_element`, not `std::max`

Comment: @NathanOliver On https://devdocs.io/cpp/algorithm/max, I see an example with a custom comparator and std::max.

Comment: @NathanOliver And by the way, `std::max_element` fails to compile as well.

Comment: Why is there an & in the closure list? I haven't seen syntax like that before.

Comment: @OrdoFlammae To capture external variables by reference-- it shouldn't matter in this case, since nothing is captured.

Comment: `std::max_element` returns an iterator, so if you're only gonna change that, of course it won't compile.

Comment: BTW, std::max will NOT work because it's meant to compare two elements, not iterators of a vector. I don't know what error you are getting with std::max_element, but that's probably a different issue.

Comment: If I _feel_ that there should be an algorithm already formalised, I go to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) and happy-search. `max` won't do it for you - but read through - there are hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing these two lines of code fixed the issue (thanks to @milleniumbug):

```
    auto hill = std::max_element(hills.begin(), hills.end(), byHeight);
    assert(hill->height == 150);
```

`*std::max_element` gets you the element itself. `std::max_element` returns an iterator, giving you an opportunity to modify the element.

Answer (score 1):

Change `std::max` to `*std::max_element` and it'll work. With the `*`.

`max_element()` returns an iterator, which `*` dereferences to get the actual element.